# Invalid object name 'Inventory'. When inserting data into SQL Database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating an application that will store data in a local database. These items are added by a separate form within the same application. I am having troubles when running the code to insert the data into the table named `Inventory`. Here is my code:

```
_instance = this;
SqlCommand sqlCmd;
SqlConnection sqlConnection;
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter;

public static void Add_Value(string ItemName, string ItemQuantity, string ItemBarcode,int imageIndex)
{
    _instance.sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug\Test.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    _instance.sqlConnection.Open();
    _instance.sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Inventory (Name,Quantity,Barcode) VALUES (@Name,@Quantity,@Barcode)",_instance.sqlConnection);
    _instance.sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ItemName);
    _instance.sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", ItemQuantity);
    _instance.sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barcode", ItemBarcode);
}
```

I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Invalid object
>   name 'Inventory'.

Any help is appreciated, and feel free to explain as if you were talking to a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Inventory table does not exist in that database.

Make sure you set the connection string correctly and try again.

Or it could be that your inventory table is defined in a Schema other than "dbo" which is the default schema...

You can try opening your database in Visual Studio to double check the schema, and then from the same connection that you open the database, you can get the correct connection string from the properties window.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! You are correct. I created a new database and table and it all magically works. I don't know exactly what I did differently as I went through the same steps, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Database=databaseName;` (or `Initial Catalog=databaseName;`) in your connection string. Without this bit you executing against master.

Comment: Aram was correct, the table did not exist and this was causing my error. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Cool. I'll leave it as it can be an issue in someone else's case.